# Combining elements of 2 dimentional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an JavaScript array:

```
var arr = [["A",["05",90]],["A",["04",240]],["A",["03",235]],["B",["00",123]],["B",["01",234]]];
```

I want final array to look like:

```
var final = [["A",[["05",90],["04",240],["03",235]]],["B",[["00",123],["01",234]]]];
```

The final array is formed by combining all the 2nd element of 2 dimensional array when the 1st element matches.
Please advice how can this be achieved in JavaScript

Comment: As these (`"A"`, `"B"`) are _Strings_ you can safely go via an _Object_ before converting back to _Array_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object keys are generally the easiest way to create groups like this

```
var tmp = {}; // temporary grouping object
// loop over data
arr.forEach(function (item) {
    // check if group started
    if (!tmp.hasOwnProperty(item[0])) {
        tmp[item[0]] = [];
    }
    // push data to group
    tmp[item[0]].push(item[1]);

});
// map temp object to results array
var results = Object.keys(tmp).map(function (key) {
    return [key, tmp[key]];
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ad48b5pc/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great solution.It works great fopr me

Comment: charlietfl, can we also add sorting logic so the final array looks like        [["A",[["03",235],["04",240],["05",90]]],["B",[["00",123],["01",234]]]]

Comment: sure...do  sort inside the last `map` part ...`tmp[key].sort(function...`

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the array you gave:

```
var arr = [["A",["05",90]],["A",["04",240]],["A",["03",235]],["B",["00",123]],["B",["01",234]]];
```

then create a new array to store the values:

```
var final = [];
```

and simply combine all of the third-level elements (such as `["05",90]` and `["01",234]`) of each second-level ones (such as `"A"` and `"B"`) by looping through the array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for(var j = 0; j < final.length; j++) {
        if(arr[i][0] == final[j][0]) {
            final[j][1].push(arr[i][1]);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        final[final.length] = [arr[i][0], [[arr[i][1][0], arr[i][1][1]]]];
    }
}
```

This is essentially a sorting method: if the "key" is equal to one in the final array, then it adds it to that one. If not, then appends it to the end of `final`.

Here's the working example on JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0h7Lhnz2/1/).

This outputs the array:

```
["A", [["05", 90], ["04", 240], ["03", 235]]], ["B", [["00", 123], ["01", 234]]]
```

as requested.

Also, as @PaulS commented, it would be recommended to use Objects instead as Strings, to make them Key-Value pairs. But in my answer I stuck with arrays.

Comment: need to test it .. creates unusual nesting